# Game Maker - Create Instance When Health Is 0

Tags: instance, game-maker, createinstance

I have five objects: `obj_Boss`, `obj_bossHealth`, `obj_GameOver`, `obj_BtnOK`, and `obj_rec2`.

This is what I want. When `obj_Boss` has no more health, `obj_GameOver` and `obj_BtnOK` will appear.

**This is my first method:**

In `obj_bossHealth`, I have these events:

> Create Event: set var `global.bossHealth to 100`
>
> Draw Event: draw_healthbar

In `obj_Boss`, I have these events:

> Collision with `obj_rec2`: set var `global.bossHealth relative to -1.5`; destroy the instance (other)
>
> No More Health: create instance of `obj_GameOver`; create instance of `obj_BtnOK`

**This is my second method:**

In `obj_bossHealth`, I have these events:

> Create Event: set var `global.bossHealth to 100`
>
> Draw Event: draw_healthbar
>
> Step Event: if `global.bossHealth is equal to 0` then create instance of `obj_GameOver` and create instance of `obj_BtnOK`

In `obj_Boss`, I have these events:

> Collision with `obj_rec2`: set var `global.bossHealth relative to -1.5`; destroy the instance (other)

**The result of both methods:**

`obj_GameOver` and `obj_BtnOK` won't appear. How can I fix this? Please explain your answer. Thanks.

I add some images: [method1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hu6cc4l3qgu06en/Untitled-1.jpg?dl=0) [method2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g94b8i6sbrcy6pl/Untitled-2.jpg?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already known my mistake.

I can't use my first method. Because I make a variable `global.bossHealth` and reduce that variable by `1.5` every time it collides. But, I put event `No More Health`, which is still at value `100`.

I use my second method. In my question, I reduce the `global.bossHealth` by `1.5`. But, `100` is not divisible by `1.5`. So, the conditions `if global.bossHealth is equal to 0` will never be *True*. I change the actions in `Step Event`. I change `if global.bossHealth is equal to 0` into `if global.bossHealth is less than or equal to 0`. Which `less than 0` can be *True*.